# C# Linq Subset Data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection as follows

```
public class Cluster
{
   public List<ClusterData> Clust { get; set; }
}
public class ClusterData
{
   public int id { get; set; }
   public int E { get; set; }
   public int N { get; set; }
   public List<ClusterData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to find data where a subset of `Clust.Data` exist in another instance of `Clust`, something like this...

```
var duplicate = !cluster.Clust.Except(cluster.Clust[p].Data).Any();
```

However, duplicates are never found even though I suspect they should be? Is this logic failing because the nested list in `Clust` is being considered when comparing against other `Clust.Data`?

Simple example below, I would like to detect that object 1 has a duplicate (object 2 and object 5) and ideally, removing them from the collection.

```
Master collection
--- Associated collection

object 1
--- object 1
--- object 2
--- object 5
object 2
--- object 1
--- object 2
--- object 5
object 3
--- object 3
object 4
--- object 4
--- object 5
object 5
--- object 1
--- object 2
--- object 5
```

See below how I am associating the collections with one another

```
 for (int p = 0; p < cluster.Clust.Count; p++)
 {
     cluster.Clust[p].Data = new List<ClusterData>();
     for (int l = 0; l < cluster.Clust.Count; l++)
     {
         //Logic logic logic
         cluster.Clust[p].Data.Add(cluster.Clust[l]);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you suspect that duplicates should be found, or you know for sure that duplicates are there?

Comment: `ClusterData` doesn't override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` meaningfully. So `Object.GetHashCode` and `Object.Equals` are used which just compare references. If they are created with `new` they are not the same reference.

Comment: Do you want to return the duplicates or just a bool to indicate if there are any?

Comment: There's no point in calling `AsEnumerable` since `Clust` is a `List`.

Comment: Also, if you want to know if there are duplicates don't use `!...Except...Any` but `cluster.Clust.Intersect(cluster.Clust[p].Data).Any();`

Comment: Please enlarge a bit on object identity, as remarked by Tim Schmelter; are the objects actually the same in your example, i.e. `object 1` which occurs as child of `object 2` is the same os `object 1` at the top of the list?

Comment: @Codor - see my edit, the objects are the same.

Comment: @DanielShillcock look at Tim Schmelters comment,  did you try implementing gethascode?

Comment: Also what are you even trying to do?   Why is everything named so poorly? I'm just guessing but you probably are storing this data wrong, and can get away with just using a Dictionary of dictionaries

Comment: @johnny5, you may be right. I am collecting a large dataset and determining if any instances of data exist in other parts of the overall collection. They do not have the match, just be a subset of it's comparing data.

Comment: @DanielShillcock, let me try to clarify the issue.  You have a large data set, you're to only find parts of the data whose is not containing itself? why aren't you just checking the Id's?

Comment: @johnny5, Initially, I have a large dataset. I perform some business logic to determine what items in the collection are associated with other items in the same collection. If data is associated with other items in the dataset, it is added as a child list of the item. Does this make sense?

Comment: yeah kinda,  but that means under that logic 
1.  All object will contain a reference two themselves.
2. Once you filter out your duplicates you won't be able to figure out that relationship anymore.

Comment: Please provide an example of what a Duplicate is.

Object 1
   Object 1
   Object 2
   Object 5
Object 2
   Object 1
   Object 2
   Object 6

are you trying to filter out the object 2. only from the second because its a duplicate in the first?  I can answer your question if you give a clear example of exactly what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, for convenience, define a function which returns the intersection of the children of two clusters.

```
IEnumerable<ClusterData> Intersect(ClusterData lhs, ClusterData rhs)
{
    return (null != lhs && null != rhs) ? lhs.Data.Intersect(rhs.Data)
                                        : Enumerable<ClusterData>.Empty();
}
```

Next one could join the sequence of clusters with itself generating all pairs using the equality comparer defined above to include all pairs.

```
var AllPairs =
    cluster.Clust.Join( cluster.Clust,
                        x => true, // return true for both sides
                        y => true, // to get the full cartesian product
                        (x,y) => new Tuple<ClusterData,ClusterData>(x,y)
                      );
```

Note that due to deferred execution, the formulation of the query itself does not actually generate the pairs yet. Next, we exclude the diagonal of the cartesian product as follows, as these pairs are not relevant - only pairs of different clusters should be evaluated.

```
var DifferentPairs = AllPairs.Where( iPair => iPair.First != iPair.Second);
```

From these, we select the first pair which has a nonempty intersection of its components.

```
var FirstDuplicate
    = DifferentPairs.FirstOrDefault( iPair => Intersect(iPair.First, iPair.Second).Any() );
```

If `FirstDuplicate` is `null`, there are no clusters which have a nonempty intersection; otherwise, the components' data intersects. If so, the intersection itselc can be obtained as follows.

```
var Sequence = Intersect(FirstDuplicate.First, FirstDuplicate.Second);
```

Comment: I find the downvote a bit surprising; is the solution considered to be wrong or too complicated?

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, however I encounter an exception within the Intersect function where rhs.Data is null. @Nkosi I assumed it to be a typo.

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the comment. I fixed the typo.

Comment: @DanielShillcock Thanks for the comment. I updated the function to return the intersection in either case.

Comment: @DanielShillcock I rejected your edit; to my understanding, your intention was to filter the member `Clust` of `Cluster`, which is a collection of `ClusterData`; if I misunderstood this, please comment.

Comment: @Codor, this logic could be avoided if he associated the clusters properly in the first place...  Also, I don't even know how you understand the problem according to his example shouldn't everything be a duplicate?

Comment: @johnny5 Well, `object 3` does not share a child with the other objects. I don't know, I was partly guessing. I wonder what the context of the problem is. If we understand the input as a digraph, iterated deletion of the intersecting objects will ultimately yield a digraph in which no directed paths converge.

Comment: @Codor,  yeah his question is very unclear, If it was more clear I bet you it would be solved way easier during the creation of the data.  Also, Why do these objects need to store a reference to themselves?

Comment: @johnny5: from what I can see of the programming intent, the embedded `List<ClusterData>` is the "home" list of the element. It also appears that the element can also be present in other lists - hence the programmer's choice to save the reference to the list. That in itself is not code-smell, IMHO.